# Substituting qubit for classical memory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I recently came across a paper that argues that we can substitute a qubit for arbitrarily large number of bits in a physical system (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0110166).

The notion of bit represent classical information. This then implies qubit can hold a huge amount of information. On the other hand, we have Helovo bound that we can access (or extract) the information from qubit up to two bits only. That is, Helovo bound is about the amount of information that we can extract from a superposition representing states of qubit, it is not about the information that qubit is carrying with it.

In classical system, such as deterministic finite automata (DFA), state actually represent the memory. The number of states of a DFA is the size of the memory. Here we can't do that. The state space of a qubit is represented by complex linear combination of two basis states (with normalization condition) is of infinite size. Considering each state as a bit is perhaps the reason that we may substitute a qubit for arbitrarily large number of bits, and that I believe we can do before the act of measurement. So if a qubit represent the quantum memory how can we compare its size with classical memory?

Here is another paper that claim for unbounded memory advantage provided by qubit. (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/aa82df).

Moreover, it seems that many physical system have memory of its own, it may be classical or quantum. But we usually don't take into account, at least explicitly. This is the impression I have after reading Galvao and Hardy paper mentioned above. I am not physicist therefore this impression might well be totally misplaced.

Any help clearing up my confusions (and misconceptions) is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> So if a qubit represent the quantum memory how can we compare its size with classical memory ?

You can think of a quantum computer as being an analogue computer - the state of a qubit is like the angle of a wheel or the level of water in a tube in an analogue computer. In principle you can encode an unlimited amount of information in an analogue parameter such as the angle of a wheel. However, in practice the amount of information you can usefully extract from the angle of a wheel is limited by (a) the precision with which you can control the angle and (b) the accuracy with which you can measure the angle. With a poorly designed system we may only be able to determine the "true" angle of wheel within, say, $5$ degrees either way, and it may only give us $5$ or $6$ bite of information. With a well designed system we may be able to determine the angle of the wheel within a few tenths of a degree and it may give use $10$ or more bits.

Similarly, the amount of information we can usefully extract from a quantum computer is limited by factors such as thermal noise, decoherence times and, ultimately, Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. Many of these factors depend on the exact design of the quantum computer. So their is no simple "conversion factor" between number of qubits and an equivalent amount of "classical" (i.e. digital) memory

Comment: That's a nice analogy. So what Galvao and Hardy referring to substituting a qubit for arbitrary number for bits is actually for quantum processes which may help capturing a desirable information which in turn support in solving the problem at hand.